# Rails compound WHERE clause - OR, not and

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a simple search function that checks multiple fields of a record for likeness with the search parameter. It works when I just compare a single field:

```
  key = params[:searchform][:keyword]
  fkey = '%' + key + '%'
  @games = Game.where('title LIKE ?', fkey).all
```

But I want to check other fields ('category' and 'rules' for example) for likeness also, and return records that match any of these fields. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that these fields belongs to the Game class, you should do something like:

```
rules = params[:searchform][:rules]
@games = Game.where('title LIKE ? and rules = ?', fkey, rules).all
```

And so on.